# Optimize MySQL nested select with arithmetic operation

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have this sql query running on MySQL 5.1 non-normalized table.  It works the way i want it to, but it can be quite slow. I added an index on the day column but it still needs to be faster.  Any suggestions on how to get this faster? (maybe with a join instead?)

```
SELECT DISTINCT(bucket) AS b,
       (possible_free_slots -
          (SELECT COUNT(availability)
           FROM ip_bucket_list
           WHERE bucket = b
           AND availability = 'used'
           AND tday = 'evening'
           AND day LIKE '2012-12-14%'
           AND network = '10_83_mh1_bucket')) AS free_slots
FROM ip_bucket_list
ORDER BY free_slots DESC;
```

The individual queries are fast:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(bucket) FROM ip_bucket_list;
1024 rows in set (0.05 sec)

 SELECT COUNT(availability) from ip_bucket_list WHERE bucket = 0 AND availability = 'used' AND tday = 'evening' AND day LIKE '2012-12-14%' AND network = '10_83_mh1_bucket';
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Table:

```
mysql> describe ip_bucket_list;
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id                  | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| ip                  | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| bucket              | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| availability        | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| network             | varchar(100) | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| possible_free_slots | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| tday                | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| day                 | timestamp    | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

and the DESC:

```
DESC SELECT DISTINCT(bucket) as b,(possible_free_slots - (SELECT COUNT(availability) from  ip_bucket_list WHERE bucket = b AND availability = 'used' AND tday = 'evening' AND day  LIKE '2012-12-14%' AND network = '10_83_mh1_bucket')) as free_slots FROM ip_bucket_list  ORDER BY free_slots DESC;
+----+--------------------+----------------+------+-----------------------------------------+--------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table          | type | possible_keys                           | key    | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                           |
+----+--------------------+----------------+------+-----------------------------------------+--------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | ip_bucket_list | ALL  | NULL                                    | NULL   | NULL    | NULL | 328354 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | ip_bucket_list | ref  | bucket,network,ip_bucket_list_day_index | bucket | 4       | func |    161 | Using where                     |
+----+--------------------+----------------+------+-----------------------------------------+--------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you post some sample rows and expected output? That might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would move the correlated subquery from the `SELECT` clause into the `FROM` clause, using a join:

```
SELECT distinct bucket as b,
       (possible_free_slots - a.avail) as free_slots
FROM ip_bucket_list ipbl left outer join
     (SELECT bucket COUNT(availability) as avail
      from ip_bucket_list
      WHERE availability = 'used' AND tday = 'evening' AND
             day LIKE '2012-12-14%' AND network = '10_83_mh1_bucket'
     ) on a
     on ipbl.bucket = avail.bucket
ORDER BY free_slots DESC;
```

The version in the `SELECT` clause is probably being re-run for every row (even before the `distinct` is running).  By putting it in the `from` clause, the ip_bucket_list table will be scanned only once.

Also, if you are expecting each bucket to only show up once, then I would recommend that you use `group by` rather than `distinct`.  It would clarify the purpose of the query.  You may be able to eliminate the second reference to the table altogether, with something like:

```
SELECT bucket as b,
       max(possible_free_slots -
           (case when availability = 'used' AND tday = 'evening' AND
                      day LIKE '2012-12-14%' AND network = '10_83_mh1_bucket'
                 then 1 else 0
            end)
           ) as free_slots
FROM ip_bucket_list
group by bucket
ORDER BY free_slots DESC;
```

To speed up your version of the query, you need an index on `bucket`, because this is used for the correlated subquery.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The only thing is that i needed to filter my 2nd SELECT with only results for the current bucket.

Comment: I ended up just replacing the DISTINCT with a GROUP BY clause and that sped the query way up.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the subquery into the main query - like so:

```
SELECT b.bucket AS b,
       b.possible_free_slots - COUNT(l.availability) AS free_slots
FROM ip_bucket_list b
LEFT JOIN ip_bucket_list l
       ON l.bucket = b.bucket
      AND l.availability = 'used'
      AND l.tday = 'evening'
      AND l.day LIKE '2012-12-14%'
      AND l.network = '10_83_mh1_bucket'
GROUP BY b.bucket, b.possible_free_slots
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```